# Struts2 Lifecycle of Action object

Tags: struts2

I'm newbie to Struts2 framework and i didn't really have much time to read any Struts2 books. I just learn it from YouTube. Anyway here's my question.

Supposedly my struts.xml is as per below:

```
<struts>
<package name="p1" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="org.tutorial.struts2.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="success"  type="redirect" >searchTutorialForm</result>
        <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="searchTutorialForm">
        <result>/searchForm.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>  
</struts>
```

Lets talk about package p1.

If the URL is say [http://localhost:8080/Struts2/login], the org.tutorial.struts2.action.LoginAction gets called and upon success it gets redirected to the searchTutorialForm action tag which calls the searchForm.jsp.

So the URL the client would see is [http://localhost:8080/Struts2/searchTutorialForm]
(purpose is not for the client to see [http://localhost:8080/Struts2/searchForm.jsp])

Now there are some member variables in LoginAction which is being displayed in searchForm.jsp using  tag. However using this approach they are not displayed since i think the object LoginAction is no longer in the ValueStack (after the redirect, i think??).

Of course if i do not use the above approach but instead as per below:

```
<struts>
<package name="p1" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="org.tutorial.struts2.action.LoginAction">
        <result name="success">/searchForm.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>  
</struts>
```

then the member variable in the LoginAction object is displayed in success.jsp using the  tag (but then user would see the URL [http://localhost:8080/Struts2/searchForm.jsp])

Basically my intention is for the user not to see any specific internal file or calling like .jsp or .action.

IMPORTANT NOTE:
There is no action class in action tag searchTutorialForm - basically a dummy action.

Question:
1. How do i display the member variable in LoginAction object using the first approach?
2. What is the life cycle of the LoginAction object in Value Stack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Actions are created per-request.
- A redirect causes a new request.
- Therefor objects in previous actions are no longer available.

The questions:

1. You put it in session or include them as parameters in the redirect.
2. Actions go away at the end of the request.

Comment: Is it stated directly in the Struts2 documentation anywhere that action instance lifecycle is strictly bound to the request (and that new Action instance is created each single time)?
I'm trying to find a reference somewhere..

Comment: @McBton I don’t know. IIRC it used to be; don’t know if it still is. Given that (for example) form properties are action instance properties it’s certainly Strongly Implied.

Comment: @McBton It’s on [the wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=14182#content/view/14048) but the wiki isn’t particularly well-maintained or trafficked.

Comment: I've see many mentions of this fact (single action instance per request) in the internet - but none of these are coming from the Struts2 authors (or at least sources in "close relation" to the Struts2 team).
Inspecting the code of course would work but the code may change as well - and I'd prefer to find something that is more concrete (preferably some "architecture" or "general concepts" docs - for easier reference here the "desktop version" of the wiki link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14048 ).

Comment: @McBton I mean... I'm a Struts PMC and wrote a book on it :shrug: https://struts.apache.org/volunteers, https://amzn.to/3D52mao

Comment: @McBton There is essentially **zero** chance the underlying action-per-request will change since it would break almost everything in the framwork.

Comment: Ok - the two comments above settle the situation for good. Thank you for the info and I'm sorry for being a bit ignorant ;-)